# How to Retrieve VPC ID and Subnet ID Using Python boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3, amazon-eks

I would like to see a python script that could fetch the VPC id and subnet ID after the stack has been deployed.

Information to be fetched:

[image: Information to be fetched]

I have tried using boto3 but it doesn't seem to be working.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `describe_stacks()` should include this information. What did you try that's not working?

Comment: Can you upload your code?

Comment: Hey Ali Baba. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share your code that does not work with us. Sharing your code is crucial. The Stackoverflow does not exist to write code for you, we are here to help you fix _your_ code. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jordanm mentioned, you can use `describe_stacks()` to get all resources created by that stack

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
    
    response = client.describe_stacks(
        StackName="eks-sample-vpc"
    )
    return print(response)
```

or you can use `describe_stack_resource()`

```
response = client.describe_stack_resource(
    StackName="eks-sample-vpc",
    LogicalResourceId="Subnet01" #Logical ID in you template
)
```